# Group of aggregate data as Yii2 relation

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

In my `Product` model I have the following two methods; `getOrderFeedback()` is normal relation returning an `ActiveQuery` and `getTotalAndAveFeedback()` which returns an array of aggregate data for a given `Product` record.

```
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getOrderFeedback()
{
    return $this->hasMany(OrderFeedback::className(), ['productID' => 'ID']);
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getTotalAndAveFeedback()
{
    return $this->getOrderFeedback()
        ->select(['COUNT(*) AS num',
                  'AVG(rating) AS avg',
                  'FLOOR(AVG(rating)) AS full',
                  'MOD(AVG(rating), 1) AS decimal_portion',
                  '5 - FLOOR(AVG(rating)) - CEILING(MOD(AVG(rating),1)) AS empty'])->one();
}
```

When I have a group of `Product`s and iterate over them to gather the `totalAndAveFeedback` for a single `Product`, the `ActiveQuery` is triggered causing a lazy style reading from the db. Something like the following

```
$my_products = Product::find()->with(['supplier', 'location'])
               ->where(['published' => 1])
               ->all();

# SELECT * FROM product WHERE published = 1; 
# Find all products
# SELECT * FROM supplier WHERE ID IN (s1, s2, s3);
# Eagerly load supplier
# SELECT * FROM location WHERE ID IN (l1, l2, l3, l4);
# Eagerly load location

foreach ($my_products as $product) {
   echo $product->supplier->supplier_name; 
   # supplier object available from eager loading
   echo $product->location->title;
   # location object available from eager loading
   echo $product->totalAndAveFeedback->decimal_portion; 
   # requires db access to 'lazy load' data for each product record
   # SELECT COUNT(*) AS num, AVG(rating) AS avg, FLOOR(AVG(rating)) AS full, MOD(AVG(rating), 1) AS decimal_portion, 5 - FLOOR(AVG(rating)) - CEILING(MOD(AVG(rating),1)) AS empty FROM `order_feedback` WHERE `productID`=pID
}
```

Is there a way to treat `getTotalAndAveFeedback()` as relation to allow a `joinWith()` / `with()` on a `Product` `ActiveQuery` so the data can be eagerly loaded for each `Product` and available in the same manner as the `Supplier` or `Location` relations?

I've tried removing the call to `one()` in `getTotalAndAveFeedback()` to allow the method to be treated as a relation, but the `totalAndAveFeedback` attribute of the `Product` records were all empty arrays where I'd expect an object with attributes such as `decimal_portion` as if I'd called a simple relation like `Supplier`.

Is this possible in Yii2?

Comment: It will work if you append `productID` column to select array in `getTotalAndAveFeedback()` method. BUT in eager loading you will have query like `SELECT COUNT(*) AS num, AVG(rating) AS avg, FLOOR(AVG(rating)) AS full, MOD(AVG(rating), 1) AS decimal_portion, 5 - FLOOR(AVG(rating)) - CEILING(MOD(AVG(rating),1)) AS empty FROM order_feedback WHERE productID IN ( 1,2,3...100 )` , so result of this query will be not what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getTotalAndAveFeedback()
{
    return $this->getOrderFeedback()
        ->select(['productID', 'COUNT(*) AS num',
                  'AVG(rating) AS avg',
                  'FLOOR(AVG(rating)) AS full',
                  'MOD(AVG(rating), 1) AS decimal_portion',
                  '5 - FLOOR(AVG(rating)) - CEILING(MOD(AVG(rating),1)) AS empty'])
        ->groupBy(['productID']);
}
```

As @Pa3Py6aka pointed out, the reason the array was empty when joining on the relation was without selecting the `productID` there was no link between the returned `OrderFeedback`s and the `Product`.

By adding the `groupBy(['productID'])` method call to the `ActiveQuery` each the `OrderFeedbacks` are eagerly loaded and accessible to the individual`Product` objects.